# Android app signing issue on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-console

I uploaded the app as an 'internal test' because I need to use the store to share the apps so users will be able to test in-app purchase. Somehow it did not get enrolled in app signing on first upload.
Usually I do not upload to internal test, not sure if that's what made the difference, but usually the setting is to be enrolled in app signing on upload unless you select 'opt out' which I did not do.
Now under 'app signing' tab I see the attached screenshot.
Can you help with any of these options?[image]

Answer (score 0):

All of this [is explained in the help center article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423).

If your app wasn't enrolled in Google Play App Signing before, but then you choose to enroll later, you need to give Google your signing key. In order to make the instructions easy, they are asking you how you currently sign your app, so they can give you specific instructions on how to give them your signing key.

- If you normally sign your app in Android Studio, choose the first option
- If you normally sign the app on the commandline, maybe using keystore, or gradle, and you have the key in a java keystore (probably a file with the extension `.jks`) then choose option 2
- if you normally sign your app using some other method, choose option 3

If you don't want to opt into Google Play App Signing then just go back.